# Connect to Active Directory using credential

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to connect to AD sever using C#. This is my first time playing with AD.Domain I need to connect to is abc.def.com.

This is a ASP.NET web site and it gives this error. But I can log in to same domain using "ldp.exe" by using same credential. Anyone have idea?

```
[DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007052e): Logon failure: unknown user name or bad "password.
]
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +387825
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +36
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +31
```

This is my code

```
static System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
{
        System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("13.18.12.16", "Administrator", "admin123");
        ldapConnection.Path = "LDAP://ou=Users,dc=abc,dc=def,dc=com";
        ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
        return ldapConnection;
}


System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry sgscAd = createDirectoryEntry();
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher search = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(sgscAd);
search.Filter = "(cn=" + m_username + ")";

System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
```

Comment: And if you not specify an AuthenticationType ?

Comment: @tdelepine: If not specify an AuthenticationType, It gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP path to the users container is not correct.
The users container is not an *organizational unit* but a simple container.
So, you have to specify a different LDAP path.

The LDAP path to the users container in your case is:

```
LDAP://cn=Users,dc=abc,dc=def,dc=com
```

Also consider what Hall72215 mentioned in his answer. Use the whole LDAP path directly in the constructor of the `DirectoryEntry` class.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you giving one path in the constructor (`13.18.12.16`), and another by setting the Path property?  Have you tried giving all of the information in the constructor?

```
static DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
{
    string username = "Administrator";
    string password = "admin123";
    string path = "LDAP://13.18.12.16/OU=Users,DC=abc,DC=def,DC=com";
    AuthenticationTypes authType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind;
    return new DirectoryEntry(path, username, password, authType);
}
```

Is `Administrator` a user in the domain of the domain controller at `13.18.12.16`?